# DateAdd Unrecognized Identifier

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

[image: Example]

So while trying to set a parameter to a date, I get this unrecognized parameter value. I'm not sure what is causing this, I've tried many different variants ('d', "d", d, DateInterval.Day, etc.), but it is always in error. Why is dateadd not recognizing DateInterval values?

Comment: Try just "Day" this is SQL not C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: DAY, Day, "Day", and 'Day' give me the error "Incorrect number of arguments"

Comment: What if you do =DATEADD("d",7,@BillingStartDate)

Comment: I think you should also be using `Parameters!BillingStartDate.Value` and not `@BillingStartDate`. That could be the real issue.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing as @IanPreston, if you are trying to access a parameter, that is the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Ian, can't believe I overlooked that.

Comment: Cool, sometimes a guess pays off. I've added as an answer with a bit more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of issues here.

The main one is that in SSRS expression you need to refer to parameters with `Parameters!...` syntax, i.e.

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7, Parameters!BillingStartDate.Value)
```

The other issue is the expression editor itself; `DateInterval...` is perfectly valid, but the editor will highlight it as an error. It's very misleading, but despite all indications to the contrary you should be able to use `DateInterval.Day` in the expression without any issue.